# node.js restapi как проверять данные?

Tags: node.js, rest

Сам я новичок, но задача необходимая, русской документации к сожалению нет. Сделал API по видеоуроку. Все работает, но как проверять данные? Ума не приложу, к примеру прежде чем вставить продукт проверить например хэш пароля или проверить принадлежность его к другому api объекту, помогите умоляю)) Или хоть куда копать чтобы логику писать можно было? Код прикладываю:

server.js

```
// Dependecies
var express = require('express');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

// MongoDb
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/rest_test');

// Express
var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// Routes
app.use('/api', require('./routes/api'));

// Start server
app.listen(3000);
console.log('API is running on port 3000');
```

api.js

```
// Dependencies
var express = require('express');
var router = express();

// Models 
var Product = require('../models/product');


// Routes
Product.methods(['get','put','post','delete']);
Product.register(router, '/products');



// Return router
module.exports = router;
```

product.js

```
// Dependecies
var restful = require('node-restful');
var mongoose = restful.mongoose;

//Schema
var productSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
    sku: String,
    price: Number
});


//Return model
module.exports = restful.model('Products', productSchema);
```

Answer (score 1):

`express` отвечает за обработку маршрутов, `body-parser` разбирает тело запроса, `mongoose` занимается работой с MongoDB, остаётся только [`node-restful`](https://github.com/baugarten/node-restful).

У него в API есть две функции, `before` и `after`, определённые на **модели** (у вас в объекте `Product`), они принимают **HTTP-метод** (`"get"`, `"post"`, и т. д.) и [`express`-обработчик](http://expressjs.com/ru/guide/using-middleware.html).

В обработчиках действуют **все обычные правила Express**: если в нём обработка запроса должна закончиться, то надо из неё же послать ответ (`res.status(400).send("Ошибка")`?), а если можно продолжать, то нужно вызвать `next();`.

В документации к [`node-restful`](https://github.com/baugarten/node-restful) описано, что нужно поменять в `req`, чтобы изменить сохраняемые данные в `before`, и как изменить ответ для пользователя в `after`.

Comment: то есть к примеру чтобы проверить хэш я должен написать так? Product.methods(['get','put','post','delete'])
        .before('post', validhash);

function validhash(req, res, next) {
  var hash = 123;
  if (req.body.hash === 123) {
      next();
  }
  else {
      res.status(400).send("Ошибка");
  }
}

Comment: @SdafsFasafs приблизительно.

Comment: если известно подскажи пожалуйста, как получать имеющиеся данные в api в скрипте?

Comment: @SdafsFasafs для запросов в БД используется Mongoose, [его документацию и надо смотреть](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html).

Comment: да я понимаю, сделал для поля параметр unique, и получаю "errmsg": "E11000 duplicate key error collection: simple_lp.domains index: name_1 dup key: { : \"webfather.ru\" }" но как эту ошибку обработать и выдать пользователю другой ответ?

Comment: @SdafsFasafs вы перед вставкой проверяйте, что таких нет. И вообще, вы каждый свой шаг у меня спрашивать будете? Заметили, что видеоурок вас **вообще ничему не научил**? :)